# JMockit: Value of local object is getting changed while asserting

Tags: junit4, jmockit

Value of local object is getting changed while asserting. How to get the same value of local object as mocked object.

for example:

```
enter code here
public void checkStatus()
{
 ABC abc = new ABC();
 // line of code
}
```

While writing the junit test case using jmockit i have mocked the object of ABC
But while checking the value of object or asserting , the value of abc is getting changed.

```
enter code here
@Test
public void checkStatusTest(@Mocked ABC abc)
{
   new StrictExpectations()
   {
      new ABC();
      result = abc; // here value of abc is getting changed
      times=2;
   }
}
  someobject.checkStatusTest();
  assertequals(abc,new ABC());
```

}

In above test case the value of abc is getting changed. I shows the error

> java.lang.AssertionError:**ABC@3108bc** 
>   but was:**ABC5fe33**

Answer (score 2):

You haven't defined `equals()` on the `ABC` class, which means it falls through to `Object.equals()` which returns true if and only if they are the exact same object.

Now, in the `StrictExpectations` you created an `ABC` object ... and in the `assertEquals()` you created another one. Thus, they will never be equal. Nothing got changed on you; you're just dealing with two separate objects which are not equal.